# Compare hashed password with plain text password in Fauna

Tags: reactjs, next.js, faunadb

I have a collection of accounts with passwords encrypted with bCrypt in my Fauna database. How do I find the correct account when given the password in plain text?

When I was not encrypting the password, this is the query I was using:

```
const password = 'abc123'

faunaClient.query(
  q.Count( 
    q.Match(q.Index('getAccountByPassword'), password))
  )
```

But this obviously isn't going to work anymore.

So what I need to do is getting all the hashed passwords in my database and then compare them to my plain text password. I don't have a name, email or something similar, to initially identify the account and then compare the passwords. I only have the password.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index that specifies the field holding the hashes as a `term`, then you can search for the hash. You'll need to bCrypt any provided password first.

Alternately, you could use Fauna's built-in authentication. When you create a document representing an identity (e.g. a user), you can set a `credentials` field:

```
Create(
  Collection("users"),
  {
    data: {
      username: "alice",
      ...
    },
    credentials: { password: "abc123" },
  }
)
```

The `credentials` field is never stored: it is used to create a Credentials document. Then, you can use `Login(<reference to identity document>, <password>)` to acquire a token. The token's secret can then be used as a password-equivalent when executing Fauna queries, and ABAC roles can specify what privileges that the token's identity can perform.

For more details, see:

- [`Login`](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/login) function
- [`Logout`](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/logout) function
- [User Authentication](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/authentication/user) tutorial